# Why I don't see serviceWorker.js in my folder src?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I just create a react.js app and I don't see the file  serviceWorker.js I just see that into src/ :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xtGVE.png)

I precise I type that in the terminal :

`npx create-react-app myFirstApp`

Can you help me please ?

Comment: Apparently in version 2 of CRA, [service workers are opt in](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/10/01/create-react-app-v2.html). What version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

In the new versions of create-react-app there is no serviceWorker.js